# How can I improve my form?

Tags: php, forms

Currently, we're getting lots of spam. I've just added the following line:

`if ($field_budget == "" || $field_timeline == "" || $field_email == "" || $field_name == "") {
    echo "Please fill out all required form details, thank you!";
} else {`

This helped for a couple weeks, but now the spammers are back. What would be a simple, elegant way to improve my form (full code below)?

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_website = $_POST['cf_website'];
$field_company = $_POST['cf_company'];
$field_budget = $_POST['cf_budget'];
$field_custombudget = $_POST['cf_custombudget'];
$field_timeline = $_POST['cf_timeline'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

$mail_to = 'sean@seanduran.com';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor, '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'Name: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'e-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Website: '.$field_website."\n";
$body_message .= 'Company: '.$field_company."\n";
$body_message .= 'Budget: '.$field_budget."\n";
$body_message .= 'Custom Budget: '.$field_custombudget."\n";
$body_message .= 'Timeline: '.$field_timeline."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

if ($field_budget == "" || $field_timeline == "" || $field_email == "" || $field_name == "") {
    echo "Please fill out all required form details, thank you!";
} else {
    $mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

    if ($mail_status) { ?>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
            window.location = 'http://seanduran.com';
        </script>
    <?php
    }
    else { ?>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to sean@seanduran.com');
            window.location = 'http://seanduran.com';
        </script>
    <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: how about using a captcha in the form ? ?

Comment: Importantly, to help stop spammers, sanitise your data. You allow anything into your headers (and you've now publically put up the link so your first priority is to clean that up. Remove all newline characters from being injected into the header.

Comment: How do I restrict what users are allowed to put in the headers?

Comment: "Remove all newline characters from being injected into the header". Also check for invalid (non-printable) characters, the validity of the e-mail address (use PHP validation functions) and check for length - reject if over 100 characters. Just stop anyone injecting naster headers into your header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a trick maybe --

insert a text-field, hide it via CSS (the id) and check it MUST BE EMPTY!

all the spambots fill the fields with something, so just give it something like a name "address" or something...

if the bot fills it out, you can give a error...

other hint is just use [ReCaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha)

Comment: +1. I do the exact same thing

Comment: Hmm, I think I just might try that! I'd like to stay away from having to use captcha, this might be the solution.

Comment: And then a smartass bot builder will come and see that field and program his bots so that it won't work anymore. It's a nice short-term solution. ReCaptcha is the correct solution. +1.

Comment: think so, too... works mostly like a charm

Comment: it's not a general solution, but will work for a lot of spambots -- as i mentioned, recaptcha is the only way to do it more safely.

Answer (score 1):

I would introduce a Captcha. Spammers are getting good at solving these as well, but it's a good additional measure. Have a look at e.g. reCAPTCHA, it shouldn't be too hard to add (see [instructions here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php)).

Answer (score 0):

For general changes

- validate all post data. check for header injection
- captcha

Check out this article as a good start: http://www.digital-web.com/articles/bulletproof_contact_form_with_php/

Answer (score 0):

Change your name and email fields to this:

```
Name: <input type="text" name="cf_123" />
Email: <input type="text" name="cf_456" />
```

Referenced as such:

```
$field_name  = $_POST['cf_123'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_456'];
```

Then add these fields:

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="foo" />
<input type="text" name="email" class="foo" />
```

.. with this CSS:

```
.foo {
    display : none;
}
```

Then you can simply add this condition to your PHP:

```
if (!empty($_POST['name']) || !empty($_POST['email'])) {
    return false; // only a bot would see those fields and fill them out. 
}
```

Comment: autocomplete won't work anymore...

Comment: Autocomplete wouldn't recognize `cf_name` either.